# wall hung toilet advice

Tags: toilet

So… i’ve decided to go with a walmount but ended up saving a lot of money by NOT having an in-wall tank. I instead went the flush-o-meter route and discovered there’s nothing wrong with having a 5 gallon pressure tank to feed it in order to get your 25gpm flow for a few seconds so long as that tank has a back flow prevention fitting so it only supplies the toilet (all info from an engineer who does this commercially for a living). Also, my static pressure is about 90 psi. So I'm good there as well.

My question: Since I don’t need the carrier for the in-wall tank, is it OK to just beef up my 2x4 wall with pressure treated wood and mount the toilet on that? Or, do I need to make something out of steel? Or, is this all such a huge code violation that i’m out of my mind?

Keep in mind, the back side of the bathroom is a boiler room with unfinished walls. If there's a bunch of exposed steel or wood sticking into that room to support a toilet, I don't care so long as I'm not violating a lot of codes.

Comment: The toilet should have structural requirements for installation in the installation guide/online. There's also no benefit to using treated lumber inside (in fact, there's likely a detriment if you're not using proper connectors rated for PT lumber).

Comment: The toilet does not have any structural requirements that come with it other than a "recommend" carrier model number. Also, pressure treated lumber is required / code in this city when going against concrete. I am using the proper connectors. 


http://www.craneplumbing.com/productDetail.aspx?id=2915

Comment: Is it a concrete wall? Is the wood carrying the load or the concrete? I'd personally still avoid PT inside the house but I don't always agree with code. :)

Comment: Looking at the installation instructions, it looks like one key bit of info is the "The use of a Closet Carrier Support is required". I don't know what that is, exactly, but it looks like the instructions for the Closet Carrier Support are what you need to figure out the framing to accommodate it.

Comment: Actually... that brings up a good idea. I could reference specs on the carrier (they recommend a model number in the spec sheet.) Interesting, it's only $270 for that carrier. Maybe it's a waste of time/money building my own. Pressure treated lumber (already bought unfortunately) was at least 1/2 that price anyway.


I just find it hard to believe that in a commercial building, they would buy 10 carriers for 10 toilets etc. when they are all along the same wall. I figured one would just build a custom carrier out of steel/wood? Maybe not though...